# Integrating cpp-netlib to pre-existing boost package

Tags: c++, boost, cpp-netlib

I am trying to integrate cpp-netlib to my pre-existing boost package and use it in my program.

I am simply including:

```
#include <boost/network/uri.hpp>
```

and trying to use it like this:

```
boost::network::uri::uri u("http://google.com");
```

While trying to do so I am getting a linker error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
  "boost::network::uri::detail::parse(std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*>, boost::network::uri::detail::uri_parts<std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*> >&)", referenced from:
      boost::network::uri::uri::parse() in Watcher.o
```

What I have done so far is to download cpp-netlib,
building it using cmake, I believe that was successful since I can see following 3 libraries:

```
libcppnetlib-client-connections.a
libcppnetlib-server-parsers.a
cppnetlib-uri.a
```

So my question is where should I place the 3 static libraries which I have generated in order to ensure correct linking.
I already can see some library files inside directory:

```
-Boost
     -bin.v2
```

Is this the place where I have to keep my libraries to ensure correct linking.

Comment: I think you need to tell about these files to linker through some flag(For example  /MAPINFO:EXPORTS  on windows)

Comment: Hi Rahul,

I am working on OSX 10.9
What I believe is there should be a place for these libraries in boost directly structure itself, if placed there correctly they should get linked automatically ( Considering the project I am working on is already using boost libraries which requires building and I don't do anything special to use libraries like filesystem which needs to be build ).
So I need to know the place in boost root directory where these files are required to place.

Comment: Perhaps Dipak said is correct. You will have to tell linker where the libraries are.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a library path for cpp-netlib (-L) and libraries to link (-l):

```
-lcppnetlib-client-connections.a
-lcppnetlib-server-parsers.a
-lcppnetlib-uri.a
```

There is no place to put above libraries in boost folder structure. You have to pass argument when you compile you application.